# C# Structure for the settings class

Tags: c#, xml, structure

In the app I'm currently working with the user is allowed to store a lot of settings divided in different categories in XML files.

The XML could look like

```
<settings>
    <setting2>
        <setting3>
            <value1>foo</value1>
            <value2>bar</value2>
        </setting3>
        <value3>A list of strings</value3>
    </setting2>
    <setting4>
        <value4>An integer</value4>
    </setting4>
</settings>
```

The thing I'm confused about is how to best structure the class containing this information, I started out by doing a recursive class containing a list of categories and values, and now I remembered that there is a tree collection class in Java and something like that would be the best solution? 
What do you guys recommend?

Comment: You could store the settings in a XDocument ...

Comment: You may think about xml serialization deserialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just load the entire XML file into an XPathDocument? It's easy to use and quite speedy.

You could access individual settings like so:

```
XPathDocument xmldoc = new XPathDocument(settingsFile);
XPathNavigator nav = xmldoc.CreateNavigator();

foreach (XPathNavigator node in nav.Select("settings/setting2/setting3"))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Are you kidding me? It can't be that simple?

Comment: I'm afraid so... Just Google XPathDocument and XPathNavigator, you'll find useful examples!

Answer (score 1):

I would stand for more OO approach.

```
public abstract class SettingAbstract
{
   public abstract List<Setting> Children {get;set;}
   public abstract List<object>  Values {get;set}
   public XmlNode SaveMe();
}
```

and after concrete implementation for every setting type

```
public Setting2 : SettingAbstract
{
   //concrete implementation 
}


public Setting3 : SettingAbstract
{
  //concrete implementation
}
......
......
```

Something like this.